# explanation of a iptables rule

Tags: iptables

what this iptables rule does, exactly?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.7.50 --dport 422 -j DNAT --to 192.168.7.50:22
```

As far I know this rule take the packets incoming to 192.168.7.50:422
and redirect them to same ip but to a different port, isn't?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have described the rule correctly:

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.7.50 --dport 422 -j DNAT --to 192.168.7.50:22
> ```

This rule takes inbound TCP/IP packets for 192.168.7.50 for port 422 and rewrites them to port 22. (The reverse packet flow is also handled implicitly, so packets responding to an incoming session are also rewritten as if they had originated from port 422.)

Comment: Additionnal information : It looks like a rule made to "hide" the usual sshd port (22) under another port (422). (It "hides" very poorly, as it would take a few secondes for a malicious  person to find out and use that 422 port)

Comment: @OlivierDulac in practical terms I have found that moving the ssh service to another port reduces 99% of the noise associated with automated probes. That means the logs are less full, which in turn makes it easier to track and trace the more sophisticated (and therefore more dangerous) attacks. So, while we would both agree it's only "security by obscurity", I would say that there is some merit in the approach. I'd be happy to discuss this with you in a side chat if you were interested

Comment: I can understand the merit of this, but I also wanted to warn about the "poorly hides" part ^^. I may join you on that offer some other day (not right now unfortunately)

Comment: Just a note: if you are drowning in sshd logs from attacks, you should consider using wireguard - i.e. completely drop your public SSH port, and only listen on the wireguard interface. Zero sshd logs from attacks henceforth, since only you can access the SSH daemon (after your e.g. `wg-quick up wg0`).